# Putting cursor data into an array

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

Being new in Android, I am having trouble dealing with the following:

```
public String[] getContacts(){
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM contacts", null);
    String [] names = {""};
    for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i ++){
            names[i] = cursor.getString(i);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names;
}
```

The following gives me the following error:

```
09-18 10:07:38.616: E/AndroidRuntime(28165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqllitetrial/com.example.sqllitetrial.InsideDB}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5
```

I am trying to extract the data inside the cursor to an array. Can someone help me with the implementation.

Comment: its better to use arraylist instead of string[] .

Comment: Help full link For u http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
names.add(cursor.getString(i));
```

"i" is not the cursor row index, it's the column index. A cursor is already positioned to a specific row. If you need to reposition your cursor. Use cursor.move or moveToXXXX ([see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)).

For getString/Int/Long etc. you just need to tell the cursor which column you want. If you don't know the columnIndex you can use `cursor.getColumnIndex("yourColumnName")`.

Your loop should look like this:

```
public String[] getContacts(){
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM contacts", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
}
```

Comment: i forgot to call `cursor.moveToNext()` you might need to edit your code. see edit above

Comment: A couple of bugs: cursor.close(); and return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]); But thanks very much for the solution!

Comment: @Leon thanks, I've edited it. I would be so lost without my IDE + autocomplete. On a side note, it's probably a good idea to wrap the whole thing in a `try/catch` and put cursor.close() into the finally block.

Answer (score 5):

I hope its useful to you.

```
 public static ArrayList<ModelAgents> SelectAll(DbHelper dbaConnection) {
            ArrayList<ModelAgents> Agents_aList = new ArrayList<ModelAgents>();

            SQLiteDatabase sqldb = dbaConnection.openDataBase();
            Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Agents", null);
            if (cursor != null)// If Cursordepot is null then do
                                // nothing
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                    do {
                        // Set agents information in model.
                        ModelAgents Agents = new ModelAgents();
                        Agents.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TblAgents.ID)));
                        Agents.setCode(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TblAgents.CODE)));
                        Agents.setName(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(TblAgents.NAME)));

                        Agents_aList.add(Agents);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }

            sqldb.close();

            return Agents_aList;

        }
```

Comment: Can you post the ModelAgents Class?

Answer (score 3):

When cursor is returned from a database query it is placed at index -1 that is above the first entry of the cursor so, before using the cursor to get data you have move it to its first position. For that add 
    `cursor.MoveToFirst();`
after
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM contacts", null);

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  do{
    for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i ++){
      names.add(cursor.getString(i));
    }
  }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}

cursor.close();
```

Comment: I made a small change in the code, because there was a syntax error. Besides, instead of using 'cursor.getCount();', you should be using amount of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the data into the `ArrayList<String>` as below:

> ```
>    public ArrayList<String> getContacts(){
>         Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM contacts", null);
>         ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
>         if (cursor != null)
>         {
>             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>                 for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i ++){
>                       names.add(cursor.getString(i));
>                    }
>                }
>        cursor.close();
>      }
>      return names;
>   }
> ```