# Why is my Spinner empty?

Tags: android, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I'm making a project for university, I have a DialogFragment where I record a new animal for a database. In the form, there is a spinner that is loaded from a database. This is the "onCreate" code of DialogFragment:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_animal, null);
    Spinner spEspecies = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContratoBBDD.Especies.URI_CONTENIDO,null,null,null,null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext() ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,
                    new String[]{ContratoBBDD.Especies._id},
                    new int [] {android.R.id.text1},SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER    );

    Log.d("Tam", c.getCount() + "");
    Log.d("Col", c.getColumnCount() + "");
    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spEspecies.setAdapter(adaptador);

    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity())
            .getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

 }
```

I can see in the log and debugging that the cursor has information, as does the spinner -- but when I click in the spinner, it's empty.  Where do I lose the information?

Comment: Not sure if it's right to set the Spinner adapter as a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Try fetching the data first, putting it in an Array, creating an `ArrayAdapter` and setting it as the `SpinnerAdapter`. It's most likely setting the Spinner adapter just before the data has fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this link

[Putting cursor data into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863816/putting-cursor-data-into-an-array)

```
//the constructor
    Spinner spEspecies = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //set the value to show
    //change this line with query, better use ArrayList<String>
String Especies[] = {"Homo Sapiens","Felis Domestica","Zea mays"};
    //insert to spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> aaspEspecies = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Especies);
    // The drop down view
    aaspEspecies.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spEspecies.setAdapter(aaspEspecies);
```